# How do I read Minecraft mca files?

Tags: python, python-3.x, minecraft

I'm trying to read a mca file in python3 but when I do issues occur, Mca files are not base64 and gzip because using a nbt library doesn't work,
AND before you say it: There are issues with the anvil-parser library:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/nbt-editor/nbt-editor.py", line 141, in main
  chunk = anvil.Chunk.from_region(region, 19, 22)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/anvil/chunk.py", line 382, in from_region
return cls(nbt_data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/anvil/chunk.py", line 55, in __init__
self.data = nbt_data['Level']
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/nbt/nbt.py", line 543, in __getitem__
raise KeyError("Tag %s does not exist" % key)
KeyError: 'Tag Level does not exist'
```

also the anvil-parser module spits this out, NOT the script

Comment: You need to provide more content. What is this tag level? is it some variable you (forgot to) define?

Comment: that's from the anvil-parser library, Thats what I CANNOT use because of that error, also I didn't forget to define a variable, you should look at the anvil-parser documentation for more info

Comment: Is the world MC version 1.18? It looks like the anvilParser has some problems with this version:https://github.com/matcool/anvil-parser/issues/36. Te solution is to use a different fork of parser: https://github.com/0xTiger/anvil-parser

Comment: the world is 1.19 version

Comment: Then definitely check it out! If you look at AnvilParsers repo, you'll see that it has not been updated in over a year. 0xTigers fork should aslo work for 1.19 he says.

Comment: Or take a look here: https://github.com/Intergalactyc/anvil-new. Normal AnvilParser is not compatible with 1.16+ versions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The anvil-parser library you install with pip breaks when opening worlds from format 1.16 or higher, I got the answer from this comment by [Damiaan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15274955/damiaan):

> Is the world MC version 1.18? It looks like the
> anvilParser has some problems with this version: https://github.com/matcool/anvil-parser/issues/36.
>
> The solution is to use a different fork of parser: https://github.com/0xTiger/anvil-parser
>
> Edit: The normal version breaks on 1.16+

This comment helps a lot because I know a issue about anvil-parser and I know the correct version. So if you want to edit pre 1.16 worlds install anvil-parser with pip but if you want to edit 1.16 and above worlds then install anvil-parser from GitHub: https://github.com/0xTiger/anvil-parser